# Visualforce gauge step values inside chart

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

Is there a way to make the step values of a gauge show up on the inside of the gauge chart compared to the outside? I tried using apex:chartLabel and changing the display value but that does not seem to be it.

Example standard controller chart: [image: values inside]

Example custom controller chart [image: values outside]

I feel like if the values were on the inside then I would not have the clipping issue of the value.

Thoughts?

```
<apex:page controller="ISOGaugeController2b">
<script>
MyChart1.on('beforeconfig', function(config) {
    config.axes[0].margin=-10;
});
</script>
<apex:chart height="300" width="450" animate="true" data="{!data}">
<apex:axis type="Gauge" position="gauge" title="Dan Test"
    minimum="0" maximum="1000" steps="10">
    <apex:chartLabel display="insideStart"/>
</apex:axis>         
<apex:gaugeSeries dataField="size" donut="50">
</apex:gaugeSeries>
</apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What values did you try for `display`? Do `insideStart` / `insideEnd` not work for you?

Comment: I tried all of them, I just retried display=insideStart wihin apex:axis and then within the apex:gaugeSeries and there was no affect on the values displayed. They are still above the chart.

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit] your post to include your markup.

Comment: Did you also try setting the `position` to `bottom` (or any other value) on your `apex:axis`?

Comment: I just tried, seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to change the margin value in the apex:axis.

Example:

```
<apex:page controller="ISOGaugeController2b">
<script>
MyChart1.on('beforeconfig', function(config) {
    config.axes[0].margin=-10;
});
</script>
<apex:chart height="300" width="450" animate="true" data="{!data}">
<apex:axis type="Gauge" position="top" title="Dan Test"
    minimum="0" maximum="1000" steps="10" margin="-9"/>          
<apex:gaugeSeries dataField="size" donut="50"/>
</apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Shows up like this:

[image: Steps Inside]

Comment: Can you clarify if it is the attribute value or script value that makes the difference?

Comment: It's the attribute value. I believe the script value is moving the chart up and down within the frame, however, I can't seem to find any information on why people put that in. It's in a lot of the example gauges that I find on stack exchange,

Comment: Hmm, I would try removing it just to see if it has any effect. Still, nice find.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I can confirm that just the attribute is enough.